# Python3: counting and extracting letters out of a text

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, text-processing

I'm doing some processing tasks on a medium-sized (1.7 Mb) *Persian* text corpus. I want to make lists of three set of characters in the text:

1. alphabets
2. white spaces (including newline, tab, space, no-breaking space and etc.) and
3. punctuation.
   I wrote this:

---

```
# -*- coding:  utf8 -*-
TextObj = open ('text.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8')
import string
LCh = LSpc = LPunct = []
TotalCh = TotalPunct = TotalSpc = 0
TempSet = 'ابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی'
#TempSet variable holds alphabets of Persian language.
ReadObj = TextObj.read ()
for Char in ReadObj:
    if Char in TempSet: #This's supposed to count & extract alphabets only.
        TotalCh += 1 
        LCh.append (Char)
    elif Char in string.punctuation: #This's supposed to count puncts.
        TotalPunct += 1
        LPunct.append (Char)
    elif Char in ('', '\n', '\t'): #This counts & extracts spacey things.
        TotalSpc += 1
        LSpc.append (Char)
    else: #This'll ignore anything else.
        continue
```

But when I try:

```
print (LPunct)
print (LSpc)
```

I tried this code on both Linux and Windows 7. On both of them, the result is not what I expected at all. The punctuation's and space's lists, both contains Persian letters.

***Another question:***

How can I improve this condition `elif Char in ('', '\n', '\t'):` so that it covers all kind of space family?

Comment: Any new piece opf code?

Answer (score 1):

On line 3 you've assigned all the lists to be the same list!

Don't do this:

```
LCh = LSpc = LPunct = []
```

Do this:

```
LCh = []
LSpc = []
LPunct = []
```

The [string](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html) class has whitespace built in.

```
elif Char in string.whitespace:
    TotalSpc += 1
    LSpc.append (Char)
```

In your example you didn't actually put a space in your `''` character which also may be causing it to fail. Shouldn't this be `' '`?

Also, take into account the other answer here, this code is not very pythonic.

I'd write it like this:

```
# -*- coding:  utf8 -*-
import fileinput
import string
persian_chars = 'ابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی'
filename = 'text.txt'
persian_list = []
punctuation_list = []
whitespace_list = []
ignored_list = []

for line in fileinput.input(filename):
    for ch in line:
        if ch in persian_chars:
            persian_list.append(ch)
        elif ch in string.punctuation:
            punctuation_list.append(ch)
        elif ch in string.whitespace:
            whitespace_list.append(ch)
        else:
            ignored_list.append(ch)

total_persian, total_punctuation, total_whitepsace = \
    map(len, [persian_list, punctuation_list, whitespace_list])
```

Comment: In my actual code it is ' ' but here it's my typing mistake to enter ''. Thanks for mentioning. Does this class also supports the annoying utf no-breaking space character '\u200c' ?

Comment: I modified my code just like yours. No change in output.

Comment: Why open/close the file three times? Can't we do it in just one `with` block?

Comment: Not with that list constructor, it eats up the input. I'll post a version that only opens once.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\1\Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input('zebra.txt'):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\fileinput.py", line 263, in __next__
    line = self.readline()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\fileinput.py", line 363, in readline
    self._buffer = self._file.readlines(self._bufsize)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 215: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all as a more pythonic way for dealing with files you better to use `with` statement for opening the files which will close the file at the end of the block.

Secondly since you want to count the number of special characters within your text and preserve them separately, you can use a dictionary with the list names as the keys and relative characters in a list as value. Then use `len` method to get the length.

And finally for check the membership in whitespaces you can use `string.whitespace` method.

```
import string
TempSet = 'ابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی'
result_dict={}
with open ('text.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8') as TextObj :
    ReadObj = TextObj.read ()
    for ch in ReadObj :
       if Char in TempSet:
          result_dict['TempSet'].append(ch)
       elif Char in string.punctuation:
          result_dict['LPunct'].append(ch)
       elif Char in string.whitespace:
          result_dict['LSpc'].append(ch)

TotalCh =len(result_dict['LSpc'])
```

Comment: Okay, let me examine it.

Comment: This is bad, you're reading through the file three times when one would be enough.

Comment: @Kasramvd When I tried your original code I received this error: `Char is not defined.` So I changed `Char`to `ch`. Now output for LPunct and LSpc is two empty list: [] []

Comment: @ Markus Meskanen well, any idea?!

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I think I suffered from too much caffeine tonight :-D. Thanks for attention.

Comment: @Kasramvd I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\1\Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    result_dict['LSpc'].append(ch)
KeyError: 'LSpc'